# quick start in google cloud build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I ran the quick start

```
https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/quickstart-build
```

and in the section "View the build details", I don't see the output of the quickstart.sh file anywhere.  Where is the logs from actually running the quickstart.sh file?

Without any output from quickstart.sh, I am unsure how to log what is going on in docker so I can fix broken builds that build in docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this official tutorial, a docker container is built via Cloud Build, with only one executable bash script which is displaying the current date.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello, world! The time is $(date)."
```

Here is the Dockerfile :

```
FROM alpine
COPY quickstart.sh /
CMD ["/quickstart.sh"]
```

It means `quickstart.sh` is never executed during build phase but only at the execution step of container.

To see the output of script, you should run container (either locally on your computer, or via Cloud Shell) :

```
$ docker run gcr.io/[PROJECT-ID]/quickstart-image:latest
Hello, world! The time is Sat Jun 13 05:10:41 UTC 2020.
```

If you want to execute a script during build phase of container, you should use `RUN` command.

For example, let's create a second executable script called `build.sh` in the same directory:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello, build at $(date)."
```

Then, add it on `Dockerfile` file description :

```
FROM alpine
COPY quickstart.sh /
COPY build.sh /
RUN /build.sh
CMD ["/quickstart.sh"]
```

Now, we can build a new version of container image :

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/[PROJECT-ID]/quickstart-image
```

This time, output of `build.sh` could be seen in the details output log in Cloud Build console:

[image: Cloud build details log]

Of course, here it's just a simple example to give you a quick answer. You may check all other possible options to write a correct and clean `Dockerfile`. But it's not really linked with Cloud Build.

Comment: ohhhh @Thierry Falvo, I had it backwards then.  I thought I was going to be compile, creating a docker image in the docker image.  (ie. there are some images that have gradle, etc. to build code in the cloud).  thanks! This clears things up a bit.